# how to call a method after scrapy is done crawling all the links?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy to crawl websites and want to write specific links to a file. I have created a set of links I want to write and store them in a variable in my class. How can I get the "write_to_file" method to run after crawling is done?

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'spiderName'
allowed_domains = [DOMAIN_NAME]
start_urls = [STARTING_URL]
product_links = set()
rules = (
    # call parse_link on all links from starting url
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_link', follow=True),)
print("product link size is " + str(len(product_links)))
write_to_file(name, product_links)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a signal listener through `dispatcher`.

I would try something like:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
      # second param is instance of spider that is about to be closed.
```